# How to add currency symbol before MySQL form result

Tags: php, mysql, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Hopefully I can better explain here than my title :(

Basically I've got the working mysql bootstrap table from the below site
https://sourcecodesite.com/use-bootstrap-tables-display-data-mysql.html

I've set it up to display and fetch the results I require from my database, however I am trying to put a pound sign "£" before the sales table shows its result (as highlighted below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6jU8.png)

I have tried to edit the code like below but haven't been successful, hoping someone here can help me :)

```
{
    field: 'sales',
    title: £'Job Price',
    sortable: true,
}
```

The generation code is as followed

```html
<?php 
 require 'db.php';
   
   $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM results_tbl_1 WHERE ENG_ID='".$_SESSION['username']."'ORDER BY RECORD_ID DESC") or die(mysqli_error($con));
  $arrVal = array();
   
  $i=1;
   while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
          
      $name = array(
        'num' => $i,
        'rec'=> $rowList['RECORD_ID'],
           'call'=> $rowList['CALL_ID'],
            'eng'=> $rowList['ENG_ID'],
           'workcode'=> $rowList['Work_Code'],
           'sales'=> $rowList['Sales'],
           'paid'=> $rowList['How_Paid'],
           'invoice'=> $rowList['Invoice Number'],
           'date'=> $rowList['Date Completed']
           
     
           
           );  


       array_push($arrVal, $name); 
   $i++;   
   }
     echo  json_encode($arrVal);  
 

   mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You probably just need to use string concatenation to add the pound sign before your db output (unless you need multi-currency support). Can you share your generation code?

Comment: Try putting the pounds sign inside the quoted string, maybe?

Comment: @Andy added the code (i believe) to the main post

Comment: @RayPaseur also tried that, failed also :(

Comment: Instead of this you can concatenate pound symbol in php code where you are creating an array before encoding it into json

Comment: Assuming `sales` is the field you want the currency symbol on, you could probably do something as simple as change it to `'sales'=> '£'.$rowList['Sales'],`

Comment: Actually, you should use `&pound;` if it's going in a web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this makes sense.  We put the pounds symbol into a (hypothetical) field named "price."

```html
$name = array(
    'num' => $i,
    'rec'=> $rowList['RECORD_ID'],
    'call'=> $rowList['CALL_ID'],
    'eng'=> $rowList['ENG_ID'],
    'workcode'=> $rowList['Work_Code'],
    
    'price' => '£' . $rowList['Price'], // MAYBE SOMETHING LIKE THIS
    
    'sales'=> $rowList['Sales'],
    'paid'=> $rowList['How_Paid'],
    'invoice'=> $rowList['Invoice Number'],
    'date'=> $rowList['Date Completed']
);

array_push($arrVal, $name);
```

Comment: Glad to help.  You can accept the answer now, right? ;-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers